# Stop webview from reloading when performSegue view is used

Tags: swift, xcode, segue, wkwebview, back

So I have 2 views, one is a wkwebview, and the other, an aboutus view. In the wkwebview i have a button that goes to the aboutus view so that users can read about us. However, when they return to back to the page, the entire page refreshes, how do I stop this from happening? I had tried to check for the segue.identifier but that did not work either.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
        imageViewObject = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x:0,y: 0, width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height))
        imageViewObject.image = UIImage(named:"Image")
        self.view.addSubview(imageViewObject)

        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.isHidden = true

        let myURL = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.configuration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        webView.load(myRequest)
    }
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {

        self.view.addSubview(webView)

    }
//this is what i tried but does not work
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "about_us_view"
        {
            webView.stopLoading();
        }
    }
```

---

aboutusviewcontroller

```
import UIKit

class AboutUsViewController: UIViewController {

    var back_button: UIButton!
    var btmbar : UIImageView!
    var logo : UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds

        back_button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        back_button.setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_ako_back_inactive"), for: .normal)
        back_button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: screenHeight - 50, width: 50, height: 50)
        back_button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.backButtonObj(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        back_button.isHidden = false

        btmbar = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x:0 ,y: screenHeight-50, width:screenWidth, height: 80))
        btmbar.image = UIImage(named: "btm_background_bar")


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        self.view.addSubview(btmbar)
        self.view.addSubview(back_button)

    }

    @objc func backButtonObj(_ sender: UIButton){ //<- needs `@objc`


        performSegue(withIdentifier: "about_us_view", sender: self)

    }
    public var screenWidth: CGFloat {
        return UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    }

    // Screen height.
    public var screenHeight: CGFloat {
        return UIScreen.main.bounds.height
    }



    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Comment: I have found a couple mistakes in your code. You don't call `super.viewDidAppear` when you override `viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)` function. And if you call `view.addSubview(webView)` in `viewDidAppear` where you call `webView.removeFromSuperview()`?

Comment: @AlexSmet what do u mean? I'm a little new at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move this to `viewDidLoad()`

```
self.view.addSubview(webView)
```

viewWillAppear(), viewDidAppear() methods get's called every time you return to viewController by popping and thus adding the new instance of webview in your code.

**EDIT**

On back button action, it should pop the viewController, instead of performing the segue again.

```
@objc func backButtonObj(_ sender: UIButton){ 
   _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

}
```

Try and share results

Comment: when I do this, it is still the same. It still loads

Comment: am i suppose to replace something? when I replace your code with the perform segue, nothing happens

Comment: Have you replaced the backButtonObj(_ sender: UIButton) in AboutUsViewController ?

Comment: Hey, this works, but you have to do this first.

Check if it's embed in Navigation Controller, try:

Click StroryBoard
Select first viewController
Click Editor -> Embed in -> Navigation Controller
Hope it helps.

Comment: you have to add the embed in the navigation controller, then the navigationcontroller class detect it and can popviewcontroller,

Thank you! couldn't have done it with your help

Comment: Yes, Your viewController should be in the NavigationController to use push and pop methods. Your most welcome :)

Comment: Hey, can u please explain _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true), a little. I had to move around some views and it no longer works :(

Comment: Please read the more details here: 
 https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller